# How to use atomicModifyIORef with impure functions?

Tags: haskell

I have a code like this:

```
  changedMap <- traverseMyMap s $ itemVisitor config
  atomicModifyIORef' (theMap s) $ \_map -> (changedMap, ())
```

which should be buggy, as I understand, because I ignore `_map` argument in modification function, which means that other thread can change the map and I can traverse and update here irrelevant copy of the map. So, I should do traverse with modification in the function passing to `atomicModifyIORef'`. But it's impossible because `itemVisitor` is impure function (it makes different IO operations, logs some messages, and so on), so it's signature is `:: MyKey -> MyValue -> IO (Maybe MyValue)`.

What would be the right solution here? I thought to create some function `applyChanges` which will remove removed items, add added items and replace existing ones, something like:

```
changedMap <- traverseMyMap s $ itemVisitor config
atomicModifyIORef' (theMap s) $ \m -> (applyChanges m changedMap, ())
```

but it means 2 traversions. Is it possible to do it with one traversion only? Or maybe there is another solution to change atomically some IORef value by impure function?

Comment: Actually an `IO` is not "impure". It is not an IO operation, it is what it will do, some sort of recipe.

Comment: yes, some callback which will be called by main when it will apply beta-reduction. But I interested to the solution, not terms, excuse me please :)  How do peoples solve similar problem?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using only `IORef`s. You probably need some proper locking, e.g. using `MVar`s.

Comment: A Haskell function cannot be impure.

Comment: you are right, "impure" is not accurate term here, something like "function with effects"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variant of `atomicModifyIORef` with an effectful function is not supported by the current GHC PrimOps (the low-level primitives). Further, it can not be easily realized on standard hardware, so it is likely that it will never be implemented.

Here's how `atomicModifyIORef r f` is realized, roughly:

1. Create a thunk, `t`, representing the application of `f` to the contents of the `IORef`. Since the contents are not yet known, put a null pointer where they will go. Create a thunk, `u`, that selects the first component of `t`.
2. Read `r`. This will give a pointer to a heap object -- name this `p1`.
3. Modify the thunk `t` to install `p1` in its argument field.
4. Use a hardware-supported atomic compare-and-swap operation to replace the contents of `r` with `u` if and only if those contents are still `p1`. If that succeeds, then stop. Otherwise, go back to step 2.

`atomicModifyIORef'` is basically the same, but after the successful compare-and-swap it forces `u`.

As you can see, this is a mechanism based on speculation. If we're unlucky, we may have to read `r` and edit the argument field of `t` multiple times.

Note that compare-and-swap exists precisely to support this kind of speculation mechanisms. The steps above are pretty much standard. It is done in this way so that the memory has to be locked for a small amount of time, only during the compare-and-swap instruction.

Now, since `f` is evaluated an arbitrary time after the thunk is inserted, it is usually important that `f` is free from side effects.

If `f` has side effects whose timing or order matters, we can no longer speculate and use compare-and-swap, and need to lock the reference `r` for a long time. For that, we need proper locks like those used for `MVar`s.

Comment: That's not actually a decent approximation of how it works. :(

Comment: To add `atomic-primops` exposes a CAS on ioref

Comment: @dfeuer I browsed a bit about it, and understood the algorithm above. I might have got something wrong. If that's not accurate, please consider either posting an answer about how it really works, or amending the answer above so that's correct (if possible).

Comment: @chi, I'm sorry for the quick "You're wrong" with no explanation. I was about to go swimming, so I couldn't say more but wanted to try to limit unnecessary confusion. I've edited your answer based on my recollection of how the mechanism works. I hope my memories are correct. Please feel free to fix my presentation and any further errors I may have introduced.

Comment: Note: the reason for the mechanism being the way it is (editing a thunk in a way not done anywhere else that I know of) is to avoid any allocation whatsoever in the CAS loop.

Comment: @dfeuer It has also the nice property of evaluating the thunk only once. Thank you.

Comment: @chi, also very importantly, an expensive `f` won't make the CAS likely to fail. The thunk could in general be evaluated twice (by different threads), but the `noDuplicate#` in `unsafePerformIO` will prevent this.